# What are idiomatic ways to harmonize ^5 ^4 ^3?

Tags: harmony, voice-leading, functional-harmony

I have only learned a few chords in my harmony and voice leading book. I, I6, V, V6, ii, ii6, IV and the inversions of V7. I am now trying to harmonize this melody and so far the most idiomatic bassline to use for this descending line according to my book is a a pattern of 10ths between bass and soprano. So in this case it would be I6,V43,I with 5^4^3 in the soprano.  However, in this case it wont work because the ^6 before the descending line is a subdominant harmony and would need to go to a dominant chord. My bassline for the ^5^4^3 doesnt really work I think. That said would my only other option be V, V7 ,I?

[image: melody line in A major; scale degrees 5-6-5-4-3]

Comment: Are you required to match the rhythm of the melody and harmonize every single note independently without passing tones?  Also. . . what's the next note in the melody?  Is it to the A?  If so, I might do half-notes: A-B-D-C#.

Comment: Correct. Every note needs to be harmonized. Next note is A

Comment: Okay in that case, I'd probably go UP to D rather than down, and then just step down the scale with the melody in 10ths, finishing up-E, down-E, up-A

Comment: Are you not allowed to use repeated or held notes in the bass when harmonizing? I'd personally use only E for the bass under ^5 ^4 to go with V-V7.

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR

Idiomatically, the best options in this specific instance are:

1. The given solution
2. Parallel 10ths
3. Voice exchange

---

#### Parallel 10ths

I mention this first only to reiterate what's already written in the OP. Parallel 3rds, 6ths, and 10ths are highly idiomatic, so that's always a good place to start when considering a harmonization. See below for why it's a very good solution in this particular case.

#### Contrary motion / voice exchange

Another highly idiomatic option is to counter the soprano 5-4-3 with 3-4-5. This is called "voice exchange", because the soprano and bass (in this case) swap scale degrees 3 and 5. Harmonically this would generally be I6-IV-I64 or, less commonly, I6-ii6-iii.

Voice exchange is just a special case of contrary motion. Once could just as well accompany 5-4-3 with 1-2-3, and harmonizing with I-V43-I6.

#### Regarding IV proceeding to V

This is not the only option for IV. IV (and, less commonly, ii) can also be used to prolong a I chord. I-IV-I is a perfectly acceptable progression.

**This means that parallel tenths will work very well for the harmonization of the melody given in the OP.**

Comment: Another option is to harmonize ^4 with ^3 in the bass, which is a bit difficult to analyze harmonically, then harmonize ^3 with ^4 in the bass, which more straightforwardly yields IV7.  This is not what we tend to think of as idiomatic, and I first encountered it in the music of Aaron Copland, but the second place I encountered it was in the music of J. S. Bach.  It doesn't work if you're cadencing on ^3, but that's not the case in the example given in this question.

Comment: @phoog Big bonus points if you can find the Bach reference!

Comment: Aaron My textbook says thay intermediate  chords move to dominant chords not to tonic chords. Later in the book (because I skip ahead from time to time) it does discuss IV going back to I but the level that I am on only allows intermediate Harmony to move to dominant Harmony. Having said that, the IV chord on beat 2 cannot move to I or I6 right? Also, your I6 ii6 iii harmony involves bass notes 3-4-3 not 3-4-5. Please let me know if this is right?

Comment: Can you please explain your proposed solution of parallel tenths using I IV I for 5-4-3?

Comment: @armani I-IV-I6-V43-I

Comment: @phoog I don't think you'd figure those chords that way.  You'd treat the melodic note as an appoggiatura (and I'd probably write it as a grace note if it was classical style or earlier).  Also, if you can find that example (as Aaron also requested), I'll also give you big bonus points. :D

Comment: Thanks Aaron. That is what I wanted to do but book doesnt allow moving IV to I6. Not yet anyhow so I want to complete the exercise without using harmonies not yet covered.

Comment: @Bennyboy but it isn't an appoggiatura. In the Bach piece I have in mind, the Loure from the 5th French Suite, the harmonic rhythm is quarter notes, all voices are homophonically moving in quarter notes, and the alto voice has `G F♯ E F♯` while the bass has `F♯ G A D`. In the final cadence, the alto has `C B A B` while the bass has `B C D G`.  In the Copland (Appalachian Spring), the chord is perhaps conceived quartally, but it could also be described as `I6` with an added tone.  In C, the chord is, from bass to soprano, E G C F.

Comment: Furthermore, the chord preceding the `IV7` (or, in the first instance, `IV7/V`) in the Bach is also interesting in that it is a tone cluster.  In the first instance, it comprises the pitches `F♯ G A`, and in the second `A B C D` (the order here emphasizes the cluster rather than reflecting the voicing, which is `B A C D`).

Comment: I see, it looks like you mean bar 7 of the abovementioned piece.  Let me take a look.

Comment: @armani You've already completed the exercise using the harmonies given so far in the book. So I don't understand your OP.

Comment: @phoog I don't think trying to figure those notes, or analyze them as a cluster, serves much purpose.  In this case, a description of the motive is better.  Instead of the high F# at that cluster, think of it an octave down, and you can see a series of 10th intervals in two voices, and a run of passing notes in the "tenor" voice from A (5th of D) at the start of the bar down to E (5th of A) at the end.  Unfortunately, Gilels makes it sound like a monkey fart, but if you listen to Gould or others, you can see how the motion of the lines matters greatly, and the momentary harmony not at all.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 I agree it's totally motivated by the counterpoint, but the fact remains that (ignoring octave displacement) it's a cluster.  There's a fair number of options for harmonic analysis, but I haven't yet encountered one that I find particularly satisfying.

Comment: @phoog Yeah, I wouldn't want to be asked how to write this in figured bass.  It's interesting to think of the Baroque as an ongoing musical experiment.  I mean, simple V7 or dim vii chords wouldn't have made sense until you decided that the contrast between chaos and order, or displeasure and pleasure, were more important than harmonic homogeneity.  Those chords really say, "Don't just analyze me now, see where this is going."  I'd say moments like this "cluster" take that idea to an extreme so rare that it falls out of classical theory, which is a distillation of what was normal.

Comment: @phoog btw, thank you for that example.  It is in fact a little surprising (for me, at least, not having studied a huge amount of Bach) to see him doing that.